# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.routeName')

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

[image]

Here is my code:-

```
import React from 'react-native';
import { Router, Drawer, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Scene1 from '../../scenes/Scene1';
import Dashboard from '../../scenes/Dashboard';
import Images from '../../assets/images';

import styles from './Styles';

const Routes = () => (
    <Router
        backAndroidHandler={() => Actions.pop()}
        sceneStyle={styles.sceneStyle}
    >
            <Scene key="root">
                <Scene
                    key="scene1"
                    component={Scene1}
                    title="Scene 1"
                    navigationBarStyle={styles.navigationBarStyle}
                    navBarButtonColor={styles.navBarButtonColor}
                    titleStyle={styles.titleStyle}
                    initial
                />
                <Drawer
                    hideNavBar
                    key="dashboard"
                    drawerImage={Images.menuIcon}
                    contentComponent={Navigation}
                    drawerWidth={styles.drawerWidth}
                >
                <Scene
                    key="dashboard"
                    component={Dashboard}
                    title={strings.dashboard}
                    navigationBarStyle={styles.navigationBarStyle}
                    navBarButtonColor={styles.navBarButtonColor}
                    titleStyle={styles.titleStyle}
                    renderRightButton={renderNotificationButton}
                    />
                </Drawer>
            </Scene>
    </Router>
);

export default Routes;
```

I'm facing an issue. I have installed all npm depencies in node modules whenever I tried to run app in the device it gives an errors. All navigation working fine except drawer component;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the dependency: react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.22

try:

```
npm uninstall react-navigation && npm install react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.21
```

That issue is already known: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2718

Comment: Thanks! this works fine for me. But I have a question regardings dependencies. Is this solution need after creating a new react-native app?

Comment: if you work with react-native-router-flux@^4.0... you need this step until this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this command:

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* $TMPDIR/react-native-packagerache-* $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-*&& watchman watch-del-all && npm cache clean --force && npm i && npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

**drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'** 
 to DrawerNavigator solved my problem. Give it a try.

```
const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
HomeStack: {
        screen: AppStack
    }
},
{
    contentComponent: props => (<Sidebar {...props} />),
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
});
```